# TabletPC: OS selection in GRUB using volume and Windows buttons

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, touchscreen

I've bought an Acer P3-171 tablet and installed Ubuntu Precise Pangolin alongside with Windows on it. Unfortunately, I only can choose the OS to boot using an external hardware keyboard.

I am a realist and I do not expect GRUB to support touchscreen in observable future. However, OS selection using the only three hardware buttons available (volume up, volume down and Windows) looks totally feasible to me.

Before I download GRUB source codes and start messing with them, I want to be sure I'm not going to reinvent the wheel. Does anyone of you know if such feature has already been implemented?

Thank you in advance for your answers.